# Where can I find the Javadoc for com.ibm.designer.napi?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Lotus domino has several ways to access its objects via JAVA. One of these happens to be the NAPI for Domino Designer.  Unfortunatly the product does not ship with the javadoc for this API, so finding the correct classes and methods is exceedingly difficult. I am hoping the community can point me in the right direction to locate the JAVADOC for this specific API

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have modified my question slightly.  I am not asking for a soft, opinion based, answer.  I am looking for someone to point me to API documentation that seems to be missing from the product.  The Notes/Domino community I think is used to this sort of missing info ;)

Comment: @Richard: yes, that is the local policy. But (... only thought of after voting) is there a way to find or generate such documentation if none is supplied by the manufacturer? (Other than typing in "NAPI for Domino Designer documentation" into almighty Google and finding [something possibly related](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=API%20Documentation)...)

Comment: @Jongware, you raise good points. Perhaps you could ask it as a meta-question.

Comment: Napi is an undocumented API http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1345 . So, Java decompiler seems to be the only "documentation" here...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about the com.ibm.domino.napi bundle.  That OSGi bundle doesn't include any public APIs.  Therefore, there is no API documentation available.  You could try using it any way, but IBM may change NAPI internals from one release to the next and your application may break.